# Is it bad practice to pass the instance of an Activity as a parameter and finish() it from a different class?

Tags: java, android

I have a few Activities that use the exact same methods `logout()` and `redirect()` multiple times.

Would it be alright to use a separate class and mark these methods as `static` as follows:

```
public class AuthUtil {

public static void redirect(SessionManager manager, Activity activity) {
    manager.redirect();
    activity.finish();
}

public static void logout(SessionManager manager, Activity activity) {
    manager.logoutUser();
    activity.finish();
}

}
```

And call them from the activity by:

```
AuthUtil.logout(mSession,this);
```

Or should I be extending the Activities that use the method to a common `Activity` class and just put the methods there (except without the parameters since the methods wouldn't need them in that case)? However, I won't be able to do this if one of the activities extends `FragmentActivity`, another `ActionBarActivity`, which is actually the case for me...

Basically, I want to know if it's bad practice to call the activity's methods like that from a separate class body than its own? If so, what should I be doing?

Comment: Its better to call `logout()` and then 'finish()' into activity. Not from utility.

Comment: If I put the methods in the Activity, I'd have to write the method for each Activity that needs to `logout()`, so I'd be repeating quite a bit of code. Should I be extending each of the Activities to a common one then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not considered bad practice - but choosing that route because it is easiest may well be a decision you later regret.

You should ask yourself the following questions:

1. *Who is **responsible** for finishing the activity?*.
2. *Who knows **when** to finish the activity?*.
3. *Who knows **how** to finish the activity?* (usually the `Activity` but be certain).

In your case it could be:

- The activity itself
- The session manager
- The algorithm
- Something else entirely

Once you have answered those questions you should have a good idea how to implement.

Remember that you could also create a third object, perhaps an `ActivityManager` that takes responsibility. It could hold a list of activities that need to be `finish`ed when the `SessionManager`completes the session. You may then have:

```
sessionManager.redirect(activityManager);
```

other scenarios could result in

```
// Make sure when the session completes this activity is finished.
sessionManager.registerAttachedActivity(Activity activity);
```

or

```
// Activity must finish when redirect completes.
activity.finish(sessionManager.redirect());
```

It really isn't as simple as *good practice* and *bad practice* it's more about doing it **right**.

Comment: Could you just elaborate on what you mean by "who knows **how** to finish the activity"? I get your point about which class is responsible and which class knows when to - I just don't know what you mean exactly by the 3rd question.

Comment: @Trust - It is indeed a subtle point. In most cases (as I suggest) the object itself knows how to finish the activity so it is fair to assume in your case that the `finish` method should indeed be in `Activity`. In some circumstances (for example when using a Pool springs to mind) disposing of an object is not the responsibility of the object itself, the disposal should be performed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be alright to use a separate class and mark these methods as
>   static as follows

No. It would make very difficult to figure out where are the activities being finished by looking only at the source code of a given activity. And its also hard to see in what thread are those methods running for instance. And finally, because they are static, you'll have to add a new method if an activity needed to perform additional or different actions when redirecting or logging out.

> Or should I be extending the Activities...

In my experience it is not a good idea to tie activities to an inheritance hierarchy, and you named a few good reasons for not doing so. If you need code reuse try to use composition instead.

I'd always call `Activity.finish` from the very same activity, in fact I'd like to have the whole lifecycle picture contained in the activity's code. But this is just what my guts tell me, there's no definitive correct answer to your question.